# how can I rollback a virtualenv environment

Tags: python, unix, virtualenv

I created a virtualenvironment using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) and now I want to roll back what I have done and recreate a different virtualenvironment at a different location with different combination of modules. I know that I can just create the second one and use it while leaving the first one alone but would simply deleting the first one be enough to clean my system from it or should I use a different approach to rollback that first virtualenv setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just delete the first and use the new one. Also consider using [virtualenvwrapper](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/2.7.1) to make maintaining your virtualenv's easier.

Comment: If I just delete the first one will there be any paths, settings links left behind? or is it all in this directory and when I delete that directory all is gone.

Comment: @biomed Each environment created with `virtualenv` has its own Python binary and site-packages directory. These is not shared between different environments. So technically everything should be removed if you delete it.